# Table minipulation, on click re order listing, first column re orders correctly but other columns don't

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have created a script that orders a table on a page based on the columns it clicked. By clicking on the th of the first column, it succeeds in re order the listing, but if clicked on other th/columns the results appear to be wrong

```
$("table").on("click", "th", function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tblLst");
    var selection = $(this).text();
    var col = this.cellIndex;
    var tbl = [];
    var order = [];

    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.rows.length; rowIndex++){
        if (rowIndex > 0){
            tbl.push([]);
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < table.rows[rowIndex].cells.length; colIndex++)
                tbl[rowIndex-1].push(table.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].innerHTML);
        }           
    }   

    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.rows.length; rowIndex++){
        if (rowIndex > 0){
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < table.rows[rowIndex].cells.length; colIndex++)            
                if (colIndex == col)
                    order.push(table.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].innerHTML);                 
        }
    }

    order.sort();

    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.rows.length; rowIndex++){
        if (rowIndex > 0){              
            table.deleteRow(rowIndex);                                  
        }
    }

    for (var orderIndex = 0; orderIndex < order.length; orderIndex++){
        row = table.insertRow(orderIndex+1);            
        for (var tblRowIndex = 0; tblRowIndex < tbl.length; tblRowIndex++){             
            for (var tblColIndex = 0; tblColIndex < tbl[tblRowIndex].length; tblColIndex++){
                if (tblColIndex == col){
                    if (order[orderIndex] == tbl[tblRowIndex][tblColIndex]){
                        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < 6; colIndex++){
                            var colCurrent = row.insertCell(colIndex);
                            colCurrent.innerHTML = tbl[tblRowIndex][colIndex];
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `table.rows.length` to define the end of the loop, but in the mean time you are changing it's value.

The first loop `table.rows.length` could have a value of 5. The next round it will have a value of 4, since you're deleting entries from the table.

the best way to solve this is by using a fixed reference. In this case you could use `order` since it has the same length, and doesn't change.

```js
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < order.length; rowIndex++){             
        table.deleteRow(1);
}
```

Comment: ok, sort of understand. but the issue is on first try if i select any th other then the 1st it gives me wrong output,

Comment: ok yes it solves partially, but now the issue if any other th is clicked other then the first it doesnt no record all the rows

Comment: is your table filled with numbers?

Comment: title, price(dec), id(int)

Comment: IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

`code
for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < order.length; rowIndex++)
{table.deleteRow(rowIndex);}`

Comment: ah, your first column is text. The sort procedure always sorts alphabetically by default. That's why numbers that start with 1 will be at the top, no matter how large. You just need to change the sorting procedure for the numerical columns.